# PhoneGap is saying "listen EADDRINUSE::::3000 when press play

Tags: android, ios, cordova, server, phonegap-desktop-app

I am starting using PhoneGap, and I have this problem:
My desktop:

[image]

**My Iphone:**

[image]

I have googled my problem, and I tried what I have found but it is not fixed. So perhaps it is because I am no understanding the error...

Please help?

(first time using PhoneGap)